# Angular Deployment Using Azure DevOps pipleines in Azure Web Service with multiple GitHub repositories

Tags: node.js, angular, github, azure-devops, deployment

We have two different GitHub repositories to maintain Angular Frontend and Backend. I have successfully done the FrontEnd deployment in Azure Web service using Azure DevOps pipelines.

Now, How to configure backend(Node.Js) repositories also in Azure DevOps.